# custom text position on ipywidgets button

Tags: python, css, ipywidgets

I am trying to put a "+" sign on a button that reaches all the edges. This is a minimal example, from a Jupyter notebook, first a style:

```
%%html
<style>
.button_style{
    font-size:155px;
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

and the button itself:

```
import ipywidgets as ipyw
button = ipyw.Button(description='+', style={'button_color':'blue'},    
                     layout=ipyw.Layout(width='80px', height='80px'))
button.add_class("button_style")
```

As you can see, what I tried was making the font size big enough to reach the button edges.
But the problem is that the text is not aligned with the middle of the button:

[image]

I've played with options like `text-align`, `left-padding`, `left-margin` etc, but they all affect the entire button, i.e. they translate or deform the entire blue square, rather than just the text within it.

Is there any way to do this? Ideally I'd be able to change the center of the cross but always have it reach all edges, and without making the cross itself super fat.
But less than ideal solutions are also welcome.

**Update:**

So the result I am looking for is this:

[image]

where the center and ideally also the thickness of the lines can be configured. It doesn't matter if the result is achieved with a '+', as long as the button looks like this and the background color can still be changed with `style={'button_color': ..}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @johannchopin mentioned, this can be done with pseudo-elements. I suggest a solution similar to his but without the inner `.custom-plus` div. It's better because it will allow you to use the `ipywidgets` as-is and just add the styling.

This will allow you to use the button from `ipywidgets` like this:

#### Style

```html
%%html
<style>
.button_style {
  --size: 80px;
  --line-color: black;
  --line-color-horizontal: var(--line-color);
  --line-color-vertical: var(--line-color);
  --line-stroke: calc(0.125 * var(--size));
  --line-stroke-horizontal: var(--line-stroke);
  --line-stroke-vertical: var(--line-stroke);
  --line-distance: calc(0.2 * var(--size));
  --line-distance-right: var(--line-distance);
  --line-distance-bottom: var(--line-distance);
  --line-hover: lightblue;
  --background: blue;
  --background-hover: var(--background);
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--background);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_style:hover {
  background: var(--background-hover);
}

.button_style:hover::before, .button_style:hover::after {
  background: var(--line-hover);
}

.button_style::before, .button_style::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: background 250ms;
}

.button_style::before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: var(--line-distance-bottom);
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--line-stroke-horizontal);
  background: var(--line-color-horizontal);
}

.button_style::after {
  right: var(--line-distance-right);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--line-stroke-vertical);
  background: var(--line-color-vertical);
}
</style>
```

#### Definition

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw
button = ipyw.Button(description='+', style={'--size':'80px', '--background': 'blue' })
button.add_class("button_style")
```

You could probably also remove the layout option to define the size of the button since it's optional and we already set the size using CSS variables (`--size`). Also, using the CSS variables we can set the background color or even change colors on hover (see my snippet for an example).

```css
.button_style {
  --size: 80px;
  --line-color: black;
  --line-color-horizontal: var(--line-color);
  --line-color-vertical: var(--line-color);
  --line-stroke: calc(0.125 * var(--size));
  --line-stroke-horizontal: var(--line-stroke);
  --line-stroke-vertical: var(--line-stroke);
  --line-distance: calc(0.2 * var(--size));
  --line-distance-right: var(--line-distance);
  --line-distance-bottom: var(--line-distance);
  --line-hover: lightblue;
  --background: blue;
  --background-hover: var(--background);
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--background);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_style:hover {
  background: var(--background-hover);
}

.button_style:hover::before,
.button_style:hover::after {
  background: var(--line-hover);
}

.button_style::before,
.button_style::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: background 250ms;
}

.button_style::before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: var(--line-distance-bottom);
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--line-stroke-horizontal);
  background: var(--line-color-horizontal);
}

.button_style::after {
  right: var(--line-distance-right);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--line-stroke-vertical);
  background: var(--line-color-vertical);
}
```

```html
<button class="button_style"></button>

<button class="button_style" style="--line-distance: 35px; --background: purple; --line-hover: white"></button>

<button class="button_style" style="--line-distance-bottom: 10px; --line-distance-right: 65px; --background: hsl(348, 100%, 61%); --line-color: hsl(48, 100%, 67%); --line-hover: white"></button>

<button class="button_style" style="--line-distance-bottom: 20px; --line-distance-right: 20px; --background: orange; --line-stroke-horizontal: 25px; --line-hover: orange; --background-hover: black"></button>

<div style="margin: 1em 0">
  <button class="button_style" style="--size: 40px"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Maybe for future reference you can modify it slightly to decouple the x and y position of the intersection point, right now it's fixed on the diagonal. Then I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ;) I figured out you don't need an extra `div` element for just these 2 bars so I updated my answer @Jansen. Nice use of css variables by the way, it's definitively cleaner :+1:

Comment: @Jansen hey Jansen! changed my answer to decouple the x and y position and stroke size. Also added several more plain HTML examples to show the usage of the CSS variables. basically, you can still change both dimensions at the same time, but also can change them independently.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to create these 2 bars by using `::before` and `::after` elements in pure css:

```css
.button_style::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.button_style::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

The final result look like this:

```css
.button_style {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 155px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.button_style::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.button_style::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_style"></button>
```

Have a look at the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dwg4sfp/5/).